# How to use pl/sql on JasperReports

Tags: oracle, plsql, jasper-reports

I'm new to JasperReports and I think it's an excellent tool to reporting.
But I found a problem, the use of the functions pl / sql in jasperreports.
Who knows what is the best way to implement this.
for example, see this code

```
function UsuarioFormula return VARCHAR2 is  
usuario_v  varchar2(25);  
begin  
SELECT user  
INTO   usuario_v    
FROM   dual;  
RETURN usuario_v;  
end;
```

this code is a column of formula oracle, I need to use this code in jaspersoft studio

I'm doing tests with JasperSoft Studio Pro 7.2.0 and JasperServer Pro 7.1.0

Please help!
Regards, Pablo!

Comment: Have you read [this JasperSoft Community article](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-execute-ms-sql-stored-procedure-jasperreports-server)?

Comment: I read it, but it only talk about stored procedure, not functions
I need for functions??

Comment: Functions are just stored procedures which return a value. The advice should be completely transferable.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help!
it solved this way:
`SELECT USUARIOFORMULA     --this is the function
FROM dual`
On the data editor for Jaspersoft Studio Pro, this call a function stored on the database.

Comment: You're welcome. You should write up your solution as an answer. Not only is this allowed it is encouraged.